# ng-view not injecting content on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble with a SPA I'm trying to build using Angular. My problem is (I believe) with the ng-view. I can't seem to get it to populate my page with content from the other pages when clicking the links on my page. 
Here is my code from my **script.js** file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'challenges/Challenge3/home.html',
        controller : 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'challenges/Challenge3/about.html',
        controller : 'aboutController'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'challenges/Challenge3/contact.html',
        controller : 'contactController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'challenges/Challenge3/'
    });
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled :  true,
        requireBase : false
    });
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Home page';
    $scope.title = 'Home';
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'About page';
    $scope.title = 'About';
});

app.controller('contactController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Contact page';
    $scope.title = 'Contact';
});
```

And here is where I'm trying to inject in my **index.html** file:

```
   <body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <nav role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div ng-view></div>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**About.html**

```
<h3>About Us</h3>
<p>This is a test page.</p>
<p>Thanks for reading about us!</p>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of one of your views? for example: `about.html`?

Comment: your hash-bang is blank, change `href="#about"` to `href="/about"`